# Are there any schools of hinduism that hold the Soul to be perishable / non-eternal?

Tags: philosophy, atma, death, shad-darshana, research

Hinduism has a plethora of schools, All holding a wide variety of beliefs about the nature of the Atma. Are there any schools that hold the soul/atma to be perishable and subject to destruction?

Comment: if ātman is anitya, then it's not ātman, simply.  In other words, a siddhānta which considers ātman to be anitya, doesn't accept ātman, in the first place. For e.g. Bauddha, Cārvāka, etc. Furthermore, taking such a standpoint, would mean going against the very Veda. And no known Vaidika darśana, upholds such a standpoint, not even proper tāntrikī matas/sampradāyas (non-Buddhist) do.

Comment: Good question. To ask if the soul is perishable, one must ask, *what is the soul* to begin with? Different darshans/Vedanta commentators define it differently. Usually, a rough description is said as an - *entity that is responsible for body and subjective experiences*. If subjective experiences are higher than the body, then they must be independent of it. But a question is - does *soul* decay with time? For that, one would need to understand what is meant by *decay* - *invisibility*, or *mass* or *color*, what *decays* with time? (1/2)

Comment: Can *subjective experiencer* decay with time? The *subject* does, but what does it even mean for the *subjective experience* to decay? It disappears? or becomes non-existent? If so, it contradicts the very definition of what a soul is, because we defined it to be an entity responsible for giving subjective experience and is independent of the physical body. If it is independent of the physical body, then it shouldn't disappear or nullify even after changing 50 bodies, or even 100 ones, and neither does the body decay on the other hand - matter returns back to the earth. (2/2).

Comment: There is in Indian Philosophy. But when you ask "...in Hinduism" It is a vague reference. Some mean those who are of Indian ancestry, others are referring to the religion. Strictly speaking, all modern day Hindus (religion) are followers of the Uttara Mimamsa of Vyasa and all schools of this assert the eternity of the atman. You might look into the ancient school of Carvakas to start. Two good references - https://archive.org/details/IndianPhilosophyACriticalSurvey and https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/brahma-sutras